# Expressjs: Relative links in subfolder serving from route

Tags: node.js, express

This is driving me crazy. I don't know if it's something simple or not but I feel like it should work. I am routing subdirectory requests to an app:

`app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname + '/webapps/admin'));`

In `webapps/admin/index.html` I have this:

`<link href="styles/vendor.3b7af2c7.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Which makes sense because the file is in `/webapps/admin/styles`

But then I get this:

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://www.domain.com/styles/vendor.3b7af2c7.css"`

Why is it dropping down to the root for this relative link? How do I make it read relative properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was told to do something specific in Angular that required that I add `<base href="/" />` to the  element. This broke it.